# iframe refresh automatically at invervals

Tags: javascript, iframe, refresh, setinterval, reload

I have an iframe in a div on an html page that displays weather data from an external source.  I want to refresh this iframe so that the data is always current.  I would prefer to use something like `setinterval` at 5 minute intervals.

I have searched, I have tried to come up with my own solution, I have used suggestions from other forums.  Nothing works.  I would post some code, but I have literally tried approx. 8-10 different methods and nothing has worked.  The iframe loads when the page loads and then doesn't change until I refresh the entire page.

Some of what I have read leads me to believe that some of the solutions I have tried used to work prior to `Chrome v30`, but now have stopped working due to browser security features/changes.

I still have not had any luck getting this to work. I have tried the following:

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">
   window.onload = function() {
     setInterval(function refreshDarkSky() {

   document.getElementById('content22').contentWindow.location.reload();

     }, 90000);
   } 
  </script>
```

But the iframe doesn't reload or refresh.  I have tried using both the iframe ID and the div id that holds the iframe in the parameters.  I also have tried adding 'true' in the parentheses at the end.  but still no luck.  Any idea what am I doing wrong?!

Comment: anybody?  does nobody have an iframe successfully updating on a site currently without a whole page refresh?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('some_frame_id').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

Comment: Doesnt this just reload the entire page?  I just want the iframe to reload

Comment: I have had no luck with this suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the Src and put it again.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('youriframe');
iframe.src = iframe.src;
```

It gonna be reloaded itself.